# Need help getting old game (Slender Prison) to run with Lutris

Tags: wine, games, lutris

I'm using a new install of Ubuntu 21.04. I found an old game (came out around 2012-2013) called Slender Prison (https://www.mediafire.com/file/v7f3kjbt63o83if/PrisonV1.zip/file) and tried to get it running with Lutris.

I am getting various errors. One says:

```
globals, Line 44 attempt to call a nil value
```

I press OK and then a lot of errors saying:

```
on timer line 7 attempt to call a nil value
```

I got it working before by putting it in `.wine/drive_c` and managed to get the game running, but now I cannot get it to work.

I have some logs from Lutris here:

```
$ gamemoderun /usr/bin/wine /home/lunar/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/PrisonV1 (1)/PrisonV1.exe
Initial process has started with pid 3765
Start monitoring process.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
Can't recognise 'C:\users\lunar\Temp\ir_ext_temp_20\hide.bat' as an internal or external command, or batch script.
Caught signal 15
passing along signal to PID 3765
passing along signal to PID 3841
--terminated processes--
Monitored process exited.
Initial process has exited (return code: 15)
All monitored processes have exited.
Exit with returncode 15
```

Any help would be legendary!

Comment: "Can't recognise 'C:\users\lunar\Temp\ir_ext_temp_20\hide.bat' as an internal or external command, or batch script" fix that one ;-)  probably parts of the dir leadiny to hide.bat do not exist

Comment: i looked and i cant seem to find hide.bat

Comment: i went in newly generated (C:\users\lunar\Temp\ir_ext_temp_0) and found another  exe and ran it with lutris and it opened the only thing now is when i get to game its a green screen i can here the game but the screen is green.